# Binding CheckBoxTreeCell.selectedProperty

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

There is an interface:

```
public interface DecisionWrapper {

    boolean decision ();
    BooleanProperty decisionProperty ();
    void setDecision (boolean decision);
    String getName ();
}
```

There is also a `TreeView <DecisionWrapper>`, which displays the corresponding elements from `CheckBoxTreeItem <DecisionWrapper>`. By clicking on the `CheckBox`, in `decisionProperty` must change the value.

I understand that i can add listener to every `TreeItem`, and change `decisionProperty`. But I think it is a bad solution to the problem. I tried to make `cellFactory` where in `CheckBoxTreeCell` constructor provide `decisionProperty` as a `selectionProperty`, but apparently it does not work:

```
treeViewReport.setCellFactory (CheckBoxTreeCell.forTreeView (param -> param.getValue().decisionProperty()));
// Here, in fact, the same.
treeViewReport.setCellFactory (new Callback <TreeView <DecisionWrapper>, TreeCell <DecisionWrapper >> () {
    @Override
    public TreeCell <DecisionWrapper> call (TreeView <DecisionWrapper> param) {
      return new CheckBoxTreeCell <DecisionWrapper> (param1 -> param1.getValue().decisionProperty ());
    }
});
```

Define `TreeView`:

```
treeViewReport.setShowRoot(false);
treeViewReport.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.forTreeView(param -> param.getValue().decisionProperty()));
CheckBoxTreeItem<DecisionWrapper> root = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(new DefaultDecisionWrapper("", DecisionWrapper.WrapperType.NEW));

CheckBoxTreeItem<DecisionWrapper> newVls;
CheckBoxTreeItem<DecisionWrapper> oldVls;

if (!importResult.getNewVls().isEmpty()) {
   if (importResult.isOnlyMessages()) {
      newVls = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(new DefaultDecisionWrapper("New Messages", DecisionWrapper.WrapperType.NEW));
      List<CheckBoxTreeItem<DecisionWrapper>> messages = new ArrayList<>();
      importResult.getNewVls().get(0).getMessageWrappers().forEach(msgDecision -> messages.add(new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(msgDecision)));
      newVls.getChildren().addAll(messages);
   } else {
      newVls = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(new DefaultDecisionWrapper("New Vls", DecisionWrapper.WrapperType.NEW));
      for (DecisionVlWrapper vlDecision : importResult.getNewVls()) {
         CheckBoxTreeItem<DecisionWrapper> vl = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(vlDecision);
         List<CheckBoxTreeItem<DecisionWrapper>> messages = vlDecision.getMessageWrappers()
                            .stream()
                            .map((Function<DecisionWrapper, CheckBoxTreeItem<DecisionWrapper>>) CheckBoxTreeItem::new)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
         vl.getChildren().addAll(messages);
         newVls.getChildren().add(vl);
     }
  }
  root.getChildren().add(newVls);
}
```

Class DefaultDecisionWrapper:

```
public class DefaultDecisionWrapper implements DecisionWrapper {

    BooleanProperty decision;
    WrapperType wrapperType;
    String name;

    public DefaultDecisionWrapper(String name,WrapperType wrapperType){
        decision = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        this.wrapperType = wrapperType;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean decision() {
        return decision.get();
    }

    @Override
    public BooleanProperty decisionProperty() {
        return decision;
    }

    @Override
    public void setDecision(boolean decision) {
        this.decision.set(decision);
    }

    @Override
    public WrapperType getWrapperType() {
        return wrapperType;
    }
}
```

Prompt how to best bind a values?

**UPD:** I found temporary solution. Added new class:

```
public class CheckBoxTreeItemBind<T extends DecisionWrapper> extends CheckBoxTreeItem<T> {
    public CheckBoxTreeItemBind(T t){
        super(t);
        selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(getValue().decisionProperty());
    }
}
```

but i think, its not good too.

Comment: Can you add the code where you define the TreeItem for the TreeView?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha `CheckBoxTreeItem<DecisionWrapper> root = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(new DefaultDecisionWrapper("", DecisionWrapper.WrapperType.NEW));` When i debug, `property` value in all `TreeItem`s is null

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add code, instead of placing it in a comment.

Comment: @I.Perevoz The property may be null because you are never instantiating it. Can you add the code for `DefaultDecisionWrapper` to the question as well?

Comment: Why do you think that your solution is not good enough? From the way I see it you will either have to extend the class or add a line after every TreeItem declaration - `treeItem.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(defaultDecisionWrapper.decisionProperty());`

Comment: @ItachiUchiha, but why setCellFactory doesn't work?